# Swing transparent background not being repainted

Tags: java, swing, transparency, repaint

I have a problem using transparent backgrounds in Swing.
There are a lot of artefacts produced as swing is not repainting changed regions.

[image: buggy]

As far as I can tell there are 2 out-of-the-box ways to use transparent backgrounds:

1. an opaque component with transparent color set as background (left txt field)

**Problem**: the transparent part of the background is never refreshed -> Artefacts.

2. an non-opaque component with transparent color set as background (right txt field)

**Problem**: background is not being drawn at all.

What I do **not** want to do:

- to use timers to auto repaint the frame (super awful)
- to override paintComponent method (which actually works, but is really really awful)

I am running on Win7 x64

Aaaand here is my SSCCEEE:

**Update 1: init with invokeLater (still won't work)**

```
public class OpacityBug {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new OpacityBug();
            }
        });
    }

    static final Color transparentBlue = new Color(0f, 1f, 0f, 0.5f); 

    JFrame frame;
    JPanel content;

    JTextField txt1;
    JTextField txt2;

    public OpacityBug() {
        initFrame();
        initContent();
    }

    void initFrame() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(300, 80);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    void initContent() {
        content = new JPanel();
        content.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        content.setBackground(Color.red);
        frame.getContentPane().add(content);

        txt1 = new JTextField() {
            @Override
            public void setBorder(Border border) {
                super.setBorder(null); //nope border
            }
        };
        txt1.setText("Hi! I am Buggy!");
        txt1.setOpaque(true);
        txt1.setBackground(transparentBlue);
        content.add(txt1);

        txt2 = new JTextField() {
            @Override
            public void setBorder(Border border) {
                super.setBorder(null); //nope border
            }
        };
        txt2.setText("And I have no BG!");
        txt2.setOpaque(false);
        txt2.setBackground(transparentBlue);
        content.add(txt2);

        content.revalidate();
        content.repaint();
    }
}
```

**Update 2**

As some of you noticed, it seems Swing that swing is unable to paint transparent backgrounds.
But it is not (yet) clear to me why, I searched for the piece of code responsible for drawing the background of the component and have found the following code in ComponentUI.java :

```
public void update(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
if (c.isOpaque()) {
    g.setColor(c.getBackground());
    g.fillRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(),c.getHeight());
}
paint(g, c);
}
```

As you can see, it assumes that if a component is not opaque the background doesn't need to be repainted. I say that this is a very vague assumption.

I would propose following implementation:

```
public void update(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
if(c.isOpaque() || (!c.isOpaque() && c.isBackgroundSet())) {
    g.setColor(c.getBackground());
    g.fillRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight());
}
paint(g, c);
}
```

I simply check if the background was set at all when the component is not opaque.
This simple addition would allow us to use transparent backgrounds in swing.
At least I do not know any reasons why it should not be done that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using a semi-transparent background you are breaking Swings painting rules and Swing doesn't handle this automatically.

Basically, when the component is opaque, you promise to paint the background of the component. However, when the background is semi-transparent it is not cleared completely so you get painting artifacts.

The solution is to make the component non-opaque, which means the parent component will be painted first to completely clear the background, and then the component will paint the semi-transparent background. Something like:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel()
{
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor( getBackground() );
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
};
panel.setOpaque(false); // background of parent will be painted first
panel.setBackground( new Color(255, 0, 0, 20) );
frame.add(panel);
```

Check out [Backgrounds With Transparency](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for more information. The link also contains a class called the `AlphaContainer` which allows you to wrap any component with a transparent background.

Also, note this only applies when using partial transparency. If you want full transparency then simply make the component non-opaque:

```
component.setOpaque( false );
```

Comment: Thumbs up for providing a link. I updated my question as I see no reason why the background should not be painted on non-opaque components.

Comment: @pmkrefeld, the link explains that... and gives the solution.

Comment: As this is actually the best way to do this aside from changing the JDK definition I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should respect Swing's threading policy and have the GUI initialized on the GUI thread:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new OpacityBug());
```

I can't tell whether this is all it will take to correct the behavior on your side, but it has done just that on mine (OS X).

Comment: Unfortunately it had no effect for me. I should mention that i am runnung it on Java 6 (no Lambdas for me :)). I will try it with JDK8, hopefully it won't fix it. JDK bugs are the worst.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot stress this enough, I see a ton of people not doing this while it is vital to ensure correct behavior from Swing; ALL GUI instances must run on the EDT(Event Dispatch Thread)

Please read the below article and adjust your code and report back with the effects.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html

Comment: My actual code runs on EDT, I forgot to implement it in the SSCCE. I have updated the SSCCE to run on EDT, but it has not solved the problem.

Comment: Just to be clear you are running this code on Java6? If so does upgrading to Java7(or 8) fix this issue?

Comment: Nope, thankfully not. It would kill my day if there was a Swing bug in JDK6

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setOpaque(false)` on the component that has a problem, **and do the same with all the parents** !

For example, if you have a `JList` 'jList' inside a `JScrollPane` 'scrollPane', the whole thing being inside a `JPanel` 'jPanel', you should use :

```
jList.setOpaque(false);
scrollPane.setOpaque(false);
scrollPane.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
jPanel.setOpaque(false);
```

And yes, if you have a `JScrollPane`, you should set its viewport's opacity to false as well.

This will prevent painting problems on your components with transparent backgrounds.